# How to perform Bitwise Xor in list of list

Tags: python

suppose i have a list of lists `[[1,2,3],[1,2,3,4]]`

how can I find the xor of all the list of list elements,

since the xor of `[1^2^3]` is `0`, xor of `[1^2^3^4]` is `4` so the resultant list will be

```
[0,4]
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use list comprehension with `functools.reduce` and `operator.xor`.

```
from operator import xor
from functools import reduce

seq = [[1,2,3],[1,2,3,4]]
res = [reduce(xor, i) for i in seq]

print(res)
```

Output

```
[0, 4]
```

Edit: To get the "list that has max xor value"

This will return a "list of lists" with *all lists whose xor value is the same as that of `max_xor`*.

```
max_xor = max(res)  # from above
max_xor_lists = [i for i, j in zip(seq, res) if j == max_xor]
print(max_xor_lists)
```

Output

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

If you only need the first list that has the maximum xor value, then `max_xor_lists[0]` will give the first list that matches this condition.

If the only outcome is to get the list that has the max xor value (IOW, do not want the intermediate xor results) then as suggested by Alex in comments

```
from operator import xor
from functools import reduce, partial

seq = [[1,2,3],[1,2,3,4]]
_xor = partial(reduce, xor)
max_xor_list = max(seq, key=_xor)
print(max_xor_list)
```

Output

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: Thanks this works. also how I can print the list with maximum xor?

Comment: If you create a `partial` xor func (`_xor = functools.partial(reduce, xor)`) you can use `max` with a `key` param: `max(seq, key=_xor)`. This should do the max in a single pass

Comment: @Alex nice suggestion, but if I understand you correctly that is a one pass solution if the only outcome for the question is to get the list with the highest xor value, right? If OP wants both the individual lists of xor value and max, will my solution still be optimal? Using `max` with the `partial` `key` would recompute the xor again, correct me if I am wrong, I have edited what you have suggested

Comment: Absolutely, my comment is only useful if only the list with max_xor is required. Yes, if you've already created the `xor`s there's no point in re-computing them. Otherwise your solution is good, really just depends on whether the intermediate `res` is needed